How am I supposed to solder this tiny component with pads UNDER it?
My phone's microphone recently stopped working after falling. So I decided to try to repair it by buying this component (I guess a single microphone is in my phone, an xcover 4s, since calling with & without the speaker fails):

But the component is special in multiple ways:

it is way smaller than expected, the whole component is basically like 1mm wide, the width of the tip of my soldering iron… How can a microphone be that small??
it has no "legs", so I guess I need to solder the pads under it?? But how can I access them?
one of the pads is circular with a hole inside… Guess I don't want to solder the hole? Hopefully the sound is not supposed to enter this way.

So:

What is the name of these special components with no pads under them?
How am I supposed to solder this and unsolder the old one? Is it possible to do it with a regular soldering iron (mine is relatively thin with temperature control… but still not that thin), or do I need to get an expensive hot air solder? Do I need to solder the inner circle as well or only the two rectangular pads?
How can I test if the soldering has been done correctly since the "legs" are placed under the microphone?


What is on the other side of the PCB where the microphone needs to be attached? If there is nothing, then it could be possible to heat the solder through the PCB if you tin the pads first. You would want to use leaded solder for the best chance; low melting temperature solder is available, but it might be too brittle. (I am not a phone repair technician.)

@AndrewMorton That's a good point, I don't know yet (trying to grab as much information before opening my phone)

You could abandon the repair idea and use a plug-in or Bluetooth earphone with microphone.

@MTA beside being highly unpractical (the time to turn them on on a new phone call, the caller is already gone), some apps I use to record external sounds or video are unable to use the headphones (which anyway do not record sounds which are emitted far from them).

@tobiasBora I dont want to sound like a pain in the neck, but to my unprofessional ears it sounds like you do not actually know if this microphone part is responsible for the lack of sound on your phone. In fact it seems highly unlikely. More likely reason is: this part or some other part had bad solder and disconnected. If you are throwing the phone away, I would heat up the part of the phone where this part is with a blow drier, (removing the battery first obviously).

If you don't know the answer to this, then it also means that you don't have the soldering skills to realistically pulls this off, even if you have access to a hot air soldering station and solder paste. Which means that the correct way is to hire a PCBA assembly shop and let it solder it in their reflow oven. Which is the most professional and safe way to do it either way.

@tobiasBora OTOH a cheap external shotgun mic and adaptor cable gives far better pickup at range than a built-in mic (my phone's mic is particularly bad).  For things like the Merlin bird ID app it makes a massive difference

Update
I did it! And it worked! (though, funnily enough, the old microphone was the one that I managed to make work, so I guess the original issue was due to a break of the tin joint) How I did it:

use hot air soldering + soldering paste. This was a bit harder to get right than I would imagine (really small component ~1/2mm, and hard to judge the right amount of paste + need to heat longer than I would expect to make it melt, but at the same time you don't want to burn the component) I needed several tries to get it right.
solder the 2 pins, and put a bit of solder on the middle one to help the air to be guided. Don't put too much, I did it once and it will really lower the sound to the point you can barely hear anything.
make sure to protect the surroundings with Kapton tape. And put it correctly, I forgot one component and I unsoldered it by mistake… avoid extra work & risks!

Older answer
I will also try to answer my question to complete other questions based on my own research (and I'll update this thread if I manage to solve this). So, this microphone is a Micro Electro-Mechanical Systems (MEMS) microphone, that is basically a generic term to describe tiny sensors. This seems to be quite trendy now.
Searching for this brings several videos on youtube that can help:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CF7jIAcRisM explains the different kinds of microphone MEMS. I have a bottom-port (aka 3 pin) MEMS microphone. The seal ring must be solded with solder paste, and seems to be used to guide the air to the hole (and indeed this hole is used to transport sound, so should not be covered).
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oo07h9tbac8 shows a replacement of a MEMS microphone, with a different shape (4 connectors), using some solder paste and air gun. They also use some aluminium tape, maybe to make sure other components won't move, but I don't know if this is very standard, I would be afraid that some glue damage the circuit. See also this related one (longer one, but in indie https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOFk477IHv4)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCA7Pf3l-ug this one shows this time the exact same shape as mine. They also use solder paste, and they do put some on the ring part, just not in the middle. They manage to fix it without an air gun, by basically creating a big pile of solder paste next to the component (they glue it after removing the paint), and eating this pile to transfer the heat to the component… Not very professional, but if I'm desperate it might be helpful! And on the video, we can clearly see that some tin solder is present when they remove the first component, so this confirms that we also need to solder that part.


You use solder paste and hot air. This component is not possible to solder with a soldering iron.
Note that the word is "solder", not "weld"; welding is a very different process.

Thanks, that seems quite a challenge (but I do like challenges ^^). But do you think I should solder the round pad around the hole? This one seems to be the most challenging one. Do you know if there is a place where I could get the documentation of this component?

You're probably supposed to. And no, I have no idea where you might find documentation. Ask the manufacturer is my best suggestion.


Guess I don't want to weld the hole? Hopefully the sound is not supposed to enter this way.

Correct. You don't want to get solder in the hole. Probably that is exactly where the sound is sensed.

What is the name of these special components with no pads under them?

"Land Grid Array" or LGA.

How am I supposed to weld this and unweld the old one?

If the manufacturer had their way, you wouldn't. You'd throw it away and buy a new one.
In the factory they soldered (not welded) it with solder paste and a reflow oven.

do I need to get an expensive hot air welder?

You might be able to rework it with hot air solder system, but an experienced technician would have a much better chance of getting it right.

How can I test if the soldering has been done correctly since the "legs" are placed under the microphone?

You can inspect it with a $million x-ray inspection system.
Bottom line: phones are not designed to be re-worked by amateurs --- they are designed to fit an incredible amount of functionality into a very small device, even if that means they're very difficult to repair.

Thanks, that seems quite a challenge (but I do like challenges ^^). But do you think I should solder the round pad around the hole? This one seems to be the most challenging one. Do you know if there is a place where I could get the documentation of this component?

YOU are not supposed to solder it. The original phone manufacturer is supposed to solder it. He has the equipment, and solders all the other components at the same time. This component is not expected to be replaced.

@Fred That's weird to sell this online then ^^' And if I can't replace it, I can just throw the phone, so I have nothing to lose to try…

While all the above is true, I watched a street vendor in Hong Kong repair the newest iPhone by replacing some BGA IC with a hot air gun. This was around iPhone 4 era though but still small BGA stuff. He did manage to fix it.

@tobiasBora Technicians/tinkerers experienced with the tooling & techniques are usually who buy components like the one you are asking about here. You are welcome to sacrifice your phone in an attempt to learn the same techniques - but if your intent is to have a working phone at the end of it, it may behoove you to find someone who already owns the tooling and has mastered the techniques. If you do intend to learn about hot air reworking, youtube has a wealth of video demonstrating both correct & incorrect techniques. Practice on scrap parts to master these skills for better odds of success.

@PowerLuser Thanks, I do plan to ask experts before ruining my phone. I should have access to a fab lab & and a repair coffee with people more experienced than me, so I plan to go there. But it's not the first time I solder things on a PCB, I used to replace the power component of my laptop during covid with great success (though, without hot air, it was really complicated to unsold the previous one as a tiny part of tin was always staying on one pin so I ended up cutting the old component in parts before unsoldering it). Just the first time I do it with such a small component!

@winny As long as it works until the customer has paid and left... But well, just heating these parts up can solder a lot of problems in itself. BGA was never the most reliable connection method.

Louis Rossmann has quite a few board repair videos where he goes over the equipment that he uses for microsoldering. It might be interesting to check out if you've never seen his work.

The contacts here don't exactly form an array, so maybe ‘LGA’ is too specific, and the best term is surface-mount?

@gidds, the term "surface mount" isn't specific to components "with no pads under them" like OP asked about. It also includes BGAs that do have solder pads underneath and even things like SOIC that have leadframes that leave the leads accessible after soldering.

Just to give an update, I did manage to fix it with hot hair soldering + paste + kapton tape (see my update for details). Funnily enough the old microphone was actually working, so I guess the soldered part broke. Let's see how long this works ;-) Thanks for the help though.

You are discovering that the advances in electronic construction mean humans are not allowed. The good old days of components with legs are disappearing fast. If you fancy a little challenge then try soldering small wires to to component and then solder those wires to the board. You may then discover if the old component was at fault. Otherwise as suggested elesewhere support those guys at your local phone repair shop.

You’ll need a hot air gun and solder paste (or just wet the pads with normal solder first). It can be tricky if there are other components nearby, though you can shield them with kapton tape.
If there is nothing under the PCB in that area you might be able to heat it up from the other side with your soldering iron (or maybe even a lighter or torch if you are super careful and cover the rest of the PCB in some protective foil or tape).

Specifically, you need a hot air rework station for soldering, not a plain hot air gun that you can buy in the local tool shop.

Also note that you need to have a quite good temperature regulation. That's not something that the hot air gun used to remove paint can do.
